# How to do ajax call in an API using Framework7

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-framework-7

How can I do an ajax call using Framework7? I already know how to do ajax call using jQuery but I don't know how to do it in Framework7. I am using this for calling an API that returns data.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I edited Frameowrk7 to Framework7

Answer (score 9):

You can include jQuery or use default Dom7 library, it has the same Ajax methods:

```
var $$ = window.Dom7;

//do get request
$$.get('path-to-file.php', {id: 3}, function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});

//do post request
$$.post('path-to-file.php', {id: 3}, function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});

//get JSON request
$$.getJSON('path-to-file.js', function (json) {
  console.log(json);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is same as regular ajax calling. use $$ instead of $ since $DOM is assigned to $$.

```
$$.ajax({
    url:url2,
    data:{'json_order':jsonOrder},
    type:'POST',
    beforeSend:function(){
    myApp.showPreloader('Please Wait');
    },
    success:function(data)
    {
        myApp.hidePreloader();
        console.log(data);
        if(data =='success')
        {

            alert('success');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('no data');
        }

    }
    });
```

Comment: ou yeah! great answer!

Comment: But, when I use this answer, my App stuck at beforesend function. Do you know why?

Comment: @proofzy can you check the response from ajax call from network by inspecting

Answer (score 0):

Framework7 use a syntax similar to jQuery's ajax. A *POST* call could be as follows:

```
$$.post('auth.php', {username:'foo', password: 'bar'}, function (data) {
  $$('.login').html(data);
  console.log('Load was performed');
});
```

You can find more examples in the [DOM section](http://framework7.io/docs/dom.html) of the official Framework7 documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Framework7 comes with handy Request library to work with XHR requests (Ajax) right from the box

```
app.request.post('http://localhost:4103/api/RepIO/List', function (data) {
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

[framework7.io/docs](https://framework7.io/docs/request.html)

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be syntactically correct. Please add some explanation or link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: this link provid how to freamwork7 
 work vi ajax   :    https://framework7.io/docs/request.html